# Reliability of 3-way interaction term between correlated variables

Tags: interaction, reliability

If we have two variables, $X$ and $M$, which follow a multivariate normal distribution, have a mean of 0, are correlated ($r_{XM}$), and have known reliabilities ($\rho_X$ and $\rho_M$), then the reliability of the interaction term $XM$ ($XM = X * M$) is:

$\rho_{XM} = \frac{\rho_X*\rho_M  + r_{XM}^2 }{1 +r_{XM}^2} $

See [link1](https://jbusemey.pages.iu.edu/busemeyerPsychBull1983.pdf) (Eq. 10), [link2](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/270812.pdf?casa_token=BtGDYzsLMxIAAAAA:76bvaiqLZq1_nh_e3iCAgHuCaUn_sPOnbO-e07Rz3CQfbFopm1sP8Pg8SbKr2nO_8YXm0fvDbgW29uR_Rldq_Y7A8JW8Kvt1EL_8CQwOBmY4F-wiAZcP) (Eq. 19). Reliability can be thought of as a latent property of a measurement that is estimated. This [tutorial](https://personality-project.org/revelle/publications/rc.pa.19.pdf) is a good resource. It is generally defined as the fraction of an observed score variance that was not error:

Reliability of $X$ = $\rho_X = 1 - \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{V_x}$

Where $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ is variance of the measurement error and $V_X$ is the observed variance. In practice, *how* reliability is estimated will vary depending on what kind of measurement we are interested. See this extensive [tutorial](https://personality-project.org/revelle/publications/rc.pa.19.pdf) that reviews some of the most common methods. Note that how reliability was estimated is not germane to my question, only that it exists and is known.

Now, my question is: If we add a third variable $Z$, following all the assumptions above, which is correlated with both $X$ and $M$, with a known reliability ($\rho_Z$), what is the reliability of the interaction term $XMZ$ ($XMZ = X*M*Z$)?

**Edits:**

As an example, we can simulate some data and compute the reliability of the terms and interaction terms (note that in this simulation I'm assuming that $cor(X,MZ) = cor(M,XZ) = cor(Z,XM) = 0$, which may not actually be the case in truth, this is why I'd like to know the formula for the reliability.

```r
add.noise = function(x,rel){
  x2 = base::scale(x = (x+stats::rnorm(length(x), 0, sqrt((1-rel)/rel))),
                   center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
  return(x2)
}

estimate_three_way_rel=function(r.X.M,r.X.Z,r.M.Z,rel.X,rel.M,rel.Z,N){
  
  # Simulate two identical data sets
  
  cor.mat = matrix(data = c(1,r.X.M,r.X.Z,
                            r.X.M,1,r.M.Z,
                            r.X.Z,r.M.Z,1),nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)
  
  d1 = MASS::mvrnorm(n=N, mu=rep(0,3), Sigma=cor.mat, empirical=TRUE)
  d2 = d1
  
  # add in random noise proportional to the reliability
  
  d1[,1] = add.noise(x = d1[,1],rel = rel.X)
  d1[,2] = add.noise(x = d1[,2],rel = rel.M)
  d1[,3] = add.noise(x = d1[,3],rel = rel.Z)
  
  d2[,1] = add.noise(x = d2[,1],rel = rel.X)
  d2[,2] = add.noise(x = d2[,2],rel = rel.M)
  d2[,3] = add.noise(x = d2[,3],rel = rel.Z)
  
  # compute reliabilities
  
  rel.x = cor(d1[,1],d2[,1])
  rel.m = cor(d1[,2],d2[,2])
  rel.z = cor(d1[,3],d2[,3])
  rel.xm = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,2]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,2]))
  rel.xz = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,3]))
  rel.mz = cor(c(d1[,2]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,2]*d2[,3]))
  rel.xmz = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,2]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,2]*d2[,3]))
  
  # return reliabilities
  
  return(c(rel.x,rel.m,rel.z,rel.xm,rel.xz,rel.mz,rel.xmz))
  
}
```

Now compute the reliabilities for a simulated data set:

```r
    demo.int = estimate_three_way_rel(
                                r.X.M=.3,
                                r.X.Z=.5,
                                r.M.Z=.1,
                                
                                rel.X=.8,
                                rel.M=.5,
                                rel.Z=.2,
                                
                                N=100000)
> demo.int[c(1:3)]
[1] 0.7989486 0.4997133 0.2002855
```

The reliability of the $X$, $M$, and $Z$ terms match with that was specified.

The formula for two-way reliability yields:

```r
adjust.cor = function(cor1,rel1,rel2){
  newcor = cor1*sqrt(rel1*rel2)
  return(newcor)
}

two.way.rel = function(cor1,rel1,rel2){
  newrel=((rel1*rel2)+cor1^2)/(1+cor1^2)
  return(newrel)
}

interaction.rel = function(r.X.M,r.X.Z,r.M.Z,rel.X,rel.M,rel.Z){
  
  r.X.M.new=adjust.cor(cor1 = r.X.M, rel1 = rel.X, rel2 = rel.M)
  r.X.Z.new=adjust.cor(cor1 = r.X.Z, rel1 = rel.X, rel2 = rel.Z)
  r.M.Z.new=adjust.cor(cor1 = r.M.Z, rel1 = rel.M, rel2 = rel.Z)
  
  rel.XM = two.way.rel(cor1 = r.X.M.new, rel1 = rel.X, rel2 = rel.M)
  rel.XZ = two.way.rel(cor1 = r.X.Z.new, rel1 = rel.X, rel2 = rel.Z)
  rel.MZ = two.way.rel(cor1 = r.M.Z.new, rel1 = rel.M, rel2 = rel.Z)
  
 return(c(rel.XM,rel.XZ,rel.MZ)) 
  
}

interaction.rel(  r.X.M=.3,
              r.X.Z=.5,
              r.M.Z=.1,
              
              rel.X=.8,
              rel.M=.5,
              rel.Z=.2)

[1] 0.4208494 0.1923077 0.1008991
```

This matches the reliability of the two-way interaction terms from the simulated data set:

```r
demo.int[c(4:6)]
[1] 0.41461804 0.18411966 0.09994802
```

Now, the reliability of the *three-way* interaction term in this simulation is:

```r
demo.int[7]
[1] 0.1125685
```

I'd like to know this value without having to run a simulation.

Comment: What is the definition of "reliability"?  Is it just an alias for "standard deviation"?

Comment: No, it is measurement consistency (see Wikipedia for example: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_(statistics)). You might say it is the proportion of the variance and is not attributable to measurement, error or noise.

Comment: I took a quick look at the wiki page you linked and didn't find any mathematical definition of it.  Can you update your question by including a clear definition of *the reliability of a random variable $X$*, preferably in terms of equations that shows its connection with the underlying distribution of $X$?

Comment: See my edits, and if you are unfamiliar with the concept you could also review this tutorial: https://personality-project.org/revelle/publications/rc.pa.19.pdf

Comment: So "reliability" is more like a statistic instead of a population-level parameter? That is, to calculate the reliability of $X$ , only knowing the distribution of $X$ is not enough but you will need a sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ to get "observed variance"?

Comment: If you look over the tutorial I linked, you will see that there a lot of methods for estimating reliability, depending on what kind of data you have. But yes, you need a lot more than just a distribution. It is a property of a measurement, so two measurements of the same latent variable could have different reliabilities.

Comment: Have you verified that your equation for $\rho_{XM}$ matches equation 19 of your link 2?  I gave it a few minutes of thought and concluded that they did not match.  I think the math contained in link 2 is exactly what needs to be done to give the reliability of a three variable product.

Comment: Thanks @RCarnell. I'm assuming the mean=0 for both X and M, once you account for that then it simplifies to the equation I gave. I agree that probably I need to expand/follow the math, unfortunately I'm not able to follow all of it. One major piece is that I'm not sure what C^2(X,Y) means (eq.s 14-18 in link 2), and so I can't follow why it simplifies to cor(x,y)^2 (eq. 19).

Comment: Excellent point about the expected value, and I verified that you are correct.  As far as what $C^2(X,Y)$ means, it is the $[covariance(X,Y)]^2$.  I also verified that it simplifies as the paper claims.  Finally, I tried to compute the $V(MXY)$.  In the end, you have to compute the $E(M^2X^2Y^2) - [E(MXY)]^2$.  You can simplify the $E(MXY)$ a little, but I have found no simplification of $E(M^2X^2Y^2)$ that works.  Would you be willing to accept numerical integration of the density function?

Comment: Hi @RCarnell. I did find one paper that solves for $V(XMY)$ - https://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/ijsp/article/view/62832 (bottom of pg. 3). Is that helpful enough to avoid numerical integration?

Comment: @DavidB that was the missing piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the result for the variance of three way interaction of correlated variables [here](https://www.ccsenet.org/journal/index.php/ijsp/article/view/62832):

(shortened version)

$$V(XMZ) = \sigma^2_{XMZ} = E(X^2M^2Z^2) - [E(XMZ)]^2$$

(reference notation)

$$ = \sigma_{11}(\sigma_{22}\sigma_{33} + 2\sigma_{23}^2) + 2\sigma_{12}(\sigma_{12}\sigma_{33} + 2\sigma_{13}\sigma_{23}) + 2\sigma_{13}(2\sigma_{12}\sigma_{23} + \sigma_{13}\sigma_{22})$$

(notation here)

$$ = \sigma_X^2(\sigma_M^2\sigma_Z^2 + 2\sigma_{MZ}^2) + 2\sigma_{XM}(\sigma_{XM}\sigma_Z^2 + 2\sigma_{XZ}\sigma_{MZ}) + 2\sigma_{XZ}(2\sigma_{XM}\sigma_{MZ} + \sigma_{XZ}\sigma_M^2)$$

Using the notation of this [reference](https://www.jstor.org/stable/270812):

$$\rho_X = \frac{\sigma_{T,X}^2}{\sigma_{X}^2}$$

$$\rho_{XMZ} = \frac{\sigma_{T,XMZ}^2}{\sigma_{XMZ}^2}$$

$$ = \frac{\sigma_{T,X}^2(\sigma_{T,M}^2\sigma_{T,Z}^2 + 2\sigma_{MZ}^2) + 2\sigma_{XM}(\sigma_{XM}\sigma_{T,Z}^2 + 2\sigma_{XZ}\sigma_{MZ}) + 2\sigma_{XZ}(2\sigma_{XM}\sigma_{MZ} + \sigma_{XZ}\sigma_{T,M}^2)}{\sigma_X^2(\sigma_M^2\sigma_Z^2 + 2\sigma_{MZ}^2) + 2\sigma_{XM}(\sigma_{XM}\sigma_Z^2 + 2\sigma_{XZ}\sigma_{MZ}) + 2\sigma_{XZ}(2\sigma_{XM}\sigma_{MZ} + \sigma_{XZ}\sigma_M^2)}$$

##### Simulation

Starting with my own simulation...

```r
set.seed(1403949)
N <- 100000
S <- matrix(c(1, .3, .7,
              .3, 3, .4,
              .7, .4, 5), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
error <- 2
Xt <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, mu = c(0,0,0), Sigma = S)
X <- Xt + rnorm(3*N, 0, sqrt(error))

## Check Sample Variance vs Theoretical variance

var(Xt)
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.9979354 0.2911005 0.7033502
#> [2,] 0.2911005 2.9848208 0.4028383
#> [3,] 0.7033502 0.4028383 5.0007352
S
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.0  0.3  0.7
#> [2,]  0.3  3.0  0.4
#> [3,]  0.7  0.4  5.0

var(X)
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 2.9939103 0.2894055 0.6979344
#> [2,] 0.2894055 5.0110680 0.4188717
#> [3,] 0.6979344 0.4188717 7.0286428
S + diag(3)*error
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  3.0  0.3  0.7
#> [2,]  0.3  5.0  0.4
#> [3,]  0.7  0.4  7.0

for (i in 1:2) 
{
  for (j in (i+1):3) 
  {
    print(paste(i, j, var(X[,i]*X[,j])))
    print((S[i,i]+error)*(S[j,j]+error) + S[i,j]^2)
  }
}
#> [1] "1 2 15.1145101901148"
#> [1] 15.09
#> [1] "1 3 21.6049535467542"
#> [1] 21.49
#> [1] "2 3 35.0236533929537"
#> [1] 35.16

var(apply(Xt, 1, prod))
#> [1] 19.64158
S[1,1]*(S[2,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
  2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
  2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*S[2,2])
#> [1] 19.832

var(apply(X, 1, prod))
#> [1] 112.8418
(S[1,1]+error)*((S[2,2]+error)*(S[3,3]+error) + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
  2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*(S[3,3] + error) + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
  2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*(S[2,2] + error))
#> [1] 112.792

## Check sample reliability vs theoretical reliability

1 - error / (S[1,1] + error)
#> [1] 0.3333333
var(Xt[,1]) / var(X[,1])
#> [1] 0.3333217
cor(Xt[,1], X[,1])^2
#> [1] 0.3335976

(S[1,1]*S[2,2] + S[1,2]^2) / ((S[1,1] + error)*(S[2,2] + error) + S[1,2]^2)
#> [1] 0.2047714
var(Xt[,1]*Xt[,2]) / var(X[,1]*X[,2])
#> [1] 0.2038291
cor(Xt[,1]*Xt[,2], X[,1]*X[,2])^2
#> [1] 0.2067311

var(apply(Xt, 1, prod)) / var(apply(X, 1, prod))
#> [1] 0.1740631
cor(apply(Xt, 1, prod), apply(X, 1, prod))^2
#> [1] 0.1795337
(S[1,1]*(S[2,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
    2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
    2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*S[2,2])) / 
  ((S[1,1]+error)*((S[2,2]+error)*(S[3,3]+error) + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
     2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*(S[3,3] + error) + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
     2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*(S[2,2] + error)))
#> [1] 0.1758281
```

##### Continuing with the OP example:

```r
set.seed(29389445)

add.noise = function(x,rel){
  x2 = base::scale(x = (x+stats::rnorm(length(x), 0, sqrt((1-rel)/rel))),
                   center = T,scale = T)
  return(x2)
}

estimate_three_way_rel=function(r.X.M,r.X.Z,r.M.Z,rel.X,rel.M,rel.Z,N){
  
  # Simulate two identical data sets
  
  cor.mat = matrix(data = c(1,r.X.M,r.X.Z,
                            r.X.M,1,r.M.Z,
                            r.X.Z,r.M.Z,1),nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)
  
  d1 = MASS::mvrnorm(n=N, mu=rep(0,3), Sigma=cor.mat, empirical=TRUE)
  d2 = d1
  
  # add in random noise proportional to the reliability
  
  d1[,1] = add.noise(x = d1[,1],rel = rel.X)
  d1[,2] = add.noise(x = d1[,2],rel = rel.M)
  d1[,3] = add.noise(x = d1[,3],rel = rel.Z)
  
  d2[,1] = add.noise(x = d2[,1],rel = rel.X)
  d2[,2] = add.noise(x = d2[,2],rel = rel.M)
  d2[,3] = add.noise(x = d2[,3],rel = rel.Z)
  
  # compute reliabilities
  
  rel.x = cor(d1[,1],d2[,1])
  rel.m = cor(d1[,2],d2[,2])
  rel.z = cor(d1[,3],d2[,3])
  rel.xm = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,2]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,2]))
  rel.xz = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,3]))
  rel.mz = cor(c(d1[,2]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,2]*d2[,3]))
  rel.xmz = cor(c(d1[,1]*d1[,2]*d1[,3]),c(d2[,1]*d2[,2]*d2[,3]))
  
  # return reliabilities
  
  return(c(rel.x,rel.m,rel.z,rel.xm,rel.xz,rel.mz,rel.xmz))
  
}

demo.int = estimate_three_way_rel(
  r.X.M=.3,
  r.X.Z=.5,
  r.M.Z=.1,
  
  rel.X=.8,
  rel.M=.5,
  rel.Z=.2,
  
  N=100000)


three.way.rel <- function(r.X.M, r.X.Z, r.M.Z, rel.X, rel.M, rel.Z)
{
  S = matrix(data = c(1,r.X.M,r.X.Z,
                      r.X.M,1,r.M.Z,
                      r.X.Z,r.M.Z,1),nrow = 3,byrow = TRUE)
  
  (S[1,1]*(S[2,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
      2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*S[3,3] + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
      2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*S[2,2])) /
    ((S[1,1]/rel.X)*((S[2,2]/rel.M)*(S[3,3]/rel.Z) + 2*S[2,3]^2) + 
       2*S[1,2]*(S[1,2]*(S[3,3]/rel.Z) + 2*S[1,3]*S[2,3]) + 
       2*S[1,3]*(2*S[1,2]*S[2,3] + S[1,3]*(S[2,2]/rel.M)))
}
three.way.rel(r.X.M=.3,
              r.X.Z=.5,
              r.M.Z=.1,
              
              rel.X=.8,
              rel.M=.5,
              rel.Z=.2)
#> [1] 0.1251289

demo.int[7]
#> [1] 0.1249188
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! It's surprising to me that for the reliability of a 2-way interaction term I first had to adjust the individual correlations for reliability (via the `adjust.cor()` function), but your formula works without prior adjustment. Is the adjustment implicit in the math in some way that I'm not seeing?

Comment: The reason it was simpler in my formulation is that I stayed in the variance space instead of switching to the correlation and reliability space.  The $S$ matrix gives the $\sigma_T$ values and the reliability then allows you to switch to the overall $\sigma^2 = \sigma_T^2 / \rho$

Comment: I see, thanks! Am I correct then that I should treat `S` as a variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: Yes.  The S is a variance-covariance matrix.  You had called it a correlation matrix in your code, and that was fine because of how you simulated data, but I used the variance-covariance matrix in my derivation.